# sql-server fulltext search for multilevel list strings

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Is it possible to look up strings like 1.1.1 or 1.5.2 (multilevel paragraphs) in SQL Server using fulltext?
My sql looks like that:

```
contains (MyTable.MyColumn,'"*5.1.1*"')
```

I already tried removing the numbers from the stop word list or disabling the stop word list completely. As a result, strings like 5.1 or 1.1 are working fine (maybe internally those are getting handled as numbers?), but for numbers with 2 dots there is still no result.

Is there a way to escape those dotted strings/numbers, or any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Periods are problematic in full-text search, as they are typically treated as full stops between words.  Replacing the periods with a different character is the solution, and you can do it with minimal changes to the application.  This is a fairly lengthy script that walks you through identifying the problem and arriving at a solution.  You can skip down to the "Short Answer" version if all you want is a work around.

**Setup FullText Schema**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FT_Test](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TextData] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FT_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [ft_default] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[FT_Test] KEY INDEX [PK_FT_Test] ON ([ft_default])
     WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO)
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[FT_Test] ADD ([TextData])
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[FT_Test] ENABLE
```

**Verify Sql Server Version**

This script is designed around Sql Server 2012, but should be application to 2008 as well.
The wordbreaker changed substantially between Sql 2008 and Sql 2012 (at least for language id 1033 - US english).  The main implication is that 1-2-3 gets broken into 1, 2, 3, 1-2-3, nn1, nn2, nn3 (including 1-2-3 is new)

```
go
PRINT 'Version 14.0.4763.1000 is Sql Server 2012'
EXEC master.sys.sp_help_fulltext_system_components @component_type = 'wordbreaker', @param=1033
```

**Sql Server parses keywords semi-intelligently**

Unfortunately, that is currently working against us.  We get bloat as the same data is stored multiple times and bad search results as well.

```
go
DELETE FROM ft_test
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  
(  '1.1.1  5.2.1, 7.1.1.34.69; 12.11.10.9.8 4.6  7/13/2013  15,456.345')

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
 --Wait 5 seconds for ft index to populate

SELECT  ft_test.*, ft_content.display_term, ft_content.occurrence_count
FROM    sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('ft_test')) ft_content
        INNER JOIN dbo.FT_Test ON document_id = id
ORDER BY id, keyword
--Notice what is returned,the two digit numbers are identified, but the 1 digit numbers aren't (due to default stoplist).  
--Also, note that they are treated as distinct items and are broken up. 4.6 does show up because it is a decimal number.
--the nn* display_terms are standardized numeric (also, note how the date got standardized as dd20120713 in addition to 7/13/2013)

SELECT  *
FROM    ft_test
WHERE   CONTAINS ( *, '"5.2*"' ) -- No results, 5 and 2 are in default stopword list.

SELECT  *
FROM    ft_test
WHERE   CONTAINS ( *, '"12.11*"' ) -- periods are hard breaks, so this doesn't work either
```

**Create Customized stoplist to index single digits**

Single digits are typically not worth much in regards to full-text search, but we need them.  We'll use the default system stoplist as a basis.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST [no_numbers]
FROM SYSTEM STOPLIST
AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
go
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [no_numbers] DROP '0' LANGUAGE 'English';
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [no_numbers] DROP '1' LANGUAGE 'English';
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [no_numbers] DROP '2' LANGUAGE 'English';
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [no_numbers] DROP '3' LANGUAGE 'English';
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [no_numbers] DROP '4' LANGUAGE 'English';
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [no_numbers] DROP '5' LANGUAGE 'English';
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [no_numbers] DROP '6' LANGUAGE 'English';
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [no_numbers] DROP '7' LANGUAGE 'English';
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [no_numbers] DROP '8' LANGUAGE 'English';
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [no_numbers] DROP '9' LANGUAGE 'English';
GO
```

**Recreate our Fulltext index based off of a new stoplist**

This helps some and gets us closer to where we want to be.

```
DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.FT_Test

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[FT_Test] ( TextData) KEY INDEX [PK_FT_Test] ON ([ft_default])
     WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO, STOPLIST = [no_numbers])

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
 --Wait 5 seconds for ft index to populate

SELECT  ft_test.*, ft_content.display_term, ft_content.occurrence_count
FROM    sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('ft_test')) ft_content
        INNER JOIN dbo.FT_Test ON document_id = id 
ORDER BY id, keyword

--Progress, now single digits are showing up
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '1 1 14.123' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '5.2.1.1.14' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '1.1.3 ' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '2.2.3.3' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '6.0 88.00.00' )

--This works in the first 3 cases, but doesn't work for 2.2
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '1.1.1*'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id 
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '2.2.3.3*'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id 
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '2.2.3*'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id 
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '2.2*'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id 

--Double quoting makes it match more stuff, but still is broken.
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '"1.1.1*"'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id 
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '"1.1*"'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id
```

We're definitely closer now, but the 2.2* case above is annoying.  It's being parsed as a decimal number:

```
declare @stoplistId INT
SET @stoplistid = (SELECT stoplist_id FROM  sys.fulltext_stoplists WHERE name ='no_numbers')
SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_fts_parser('"1.1.1*"', 1033,@stoplistId, 0) 
SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_fts_parser('1.1.1*', 1033,@stoplistId, 0) 
SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_fts_parser('"1.1*"', 1033,@stoplistId, 0)
SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_fts_parser('1.1*', 1033,@stoplistId, 0)
```

**What other characters as are potential separators?**

Let's try a few and see if any jump out.  We could try something like 'XXXDOTXXX', but it's much cleaner to keep it a single character if possible.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  
(  '1-1-1 2@2@2 3#3#3 4$4$4 5%5%5 6^6^6 7&7&7 8*8*8 9=9=9 10_10_10 11|11|11 12:12:12 12:12:12:12 13"13"13"  14~14~14 15`15`15')

SELECT  ft_test.*, ft_content.display_term, ft_content.occurrence_count
FROM    sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('ft_test')) ft_content
        INNER JOIN dbo.FT_Test ON document_id = id WHERE textdata LIKE '1-1-1%'
ORDER BY id, keyword

DELETE FROM ft_test WHERE textdata LIKE '%3#3#3%'
```

It seems that a hyphen, underscore or backquote could work.  Let's examine these in more detail.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '3`3`3`4   1`2`3  6`1`2`3`4 ' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '5-5-5-6 2-3-4 6-1-2-3-4-5' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '6_6_6_7 3_4_5 7_1_2_3_4_5_6' )


SELECT  ft_test.*, ft_content.display_term, ft_content.occurrence_count
FROM    sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('ft_test')) ft_content
        INNER JOIN dbo.FT_Test ON document_id = id WHERE textdata LIKE '3`3%' OR TextData LIKE '5-5%' OR textdata LIKE '6_6%'
ORDER BY id, keyword
--Hyphen isn't looking good now, it gets stored 3 times, as numbers, as individual digits and as a full string.

--Let's try backquote:
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '"3`3*"'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id 
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '"1`2`3*"'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id 

-- these match anything with a single 6... not good... 
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '"6`*"'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id   
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '6`*'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id   

--the backquote is getting dropped when it's parsed
declare @stoplistId INT
SET @stoplistid = (SELECT stoplist_id FROM  sys.fulltext_stoplists WHERE name ='no_numbers')
SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_fts_parser('"6`*"', 1033,@stoplistId, 0) 
SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_fts_parser('6`*', 1033,@stoplistId, 0) 


--Underscore is just about all we have left.
declare @stoplistId INT
SET @stoplistid = (SELECT stoplist_id FROM  sys.fulltext_stoplists WHERE name ='no_numbers')
SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_fts_parser('"2_*"', 1033,@stoplistId, 0) 
SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_fts_parser('2_*', 1033,@stoplistId, 0) 
SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_fts_parser('2_2*', 1033,@stoplistId, 0) 
SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_fts_parser('2_2*', 1033,@stoplistId, 0) 
SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_fts_parser('2_2_*', 1033,@stoplistId, 0) 
SELECT * FROM  sys.dm_fts_parser('2_2_*', 1033,@stoplistId, 0) 


INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '6_6_66_7 77_6_6_6' )


-- 
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '"6_*"'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id     WHERE textdata LIKE '%[_]%'
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '6_*'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id     WHERE textdata LIKE  '%[_]%'
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '6_6*'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id     WHERE textdata LIKE  '%[_]%'
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '2_3*'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id     WHERE textdata LIKE  '%[_]%'
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '6_6*'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id     WHERE textdata LIKE  '%[_]%'

SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '6_6_6_7*'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id     WHERE textdata LIKE  '%[_]%'
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '"6_6_6_7*"'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id   WHERE textdata LIKE  '%[_]%'

SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '"6_6_6_*"'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id     WHERE textdata LIKE  '%[_]%'
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '"6_6_6*"'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id       WHERE textdata LIKE  '%[_]%'
SELECT  * FROM   ft_test LEFT JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ft_test,  *, '"6_6_*"'  ) ct ON ct.[key] = ft_test.id       WHERE textdata LIKE  '%[_]%'
```

## Short Answer

**Replace periods with Underscores**

Underscore is the way to go.  It is treated as a character, not as punctuation.  Sql Server can create a full text index on a computed column.  This will allow us to use a formula to "fix" the data, index it, and query it without additional storage (and also with minimal overhead).  You'll need to modify the application to query for "1_2_3" instead of "1.2.3".

```
--naive implementation
ALTER TABLE ft_test ADD [TextData_FT1]  AS ([textdata]+' '+replace([TextData],'.','_'))

--strip all characters.  You can customize to get pull out only the paragraph numbers
ALTER TABLE ft_test ADD [TextData_FT2]  AS (REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER([TextData])
,'A', ' '),'B', ' '),'C', ' '),'D', ' '),'E', ' '),'F', ' '),
'G', ' '),'H', ' '),'I', ' '),'J', ' '),'K', ' '),'L', ' '),'M', ' '),'N', ' '),
'O', ' '),'P', ' '),'Q', ' '),'R', ' '),'S', ' '),'T', ' '),'U', ' '),'V', ' '),
'W', ' '),'X', ' '),'Y', ' '),'Z', ' '), '.','_') , '  ',' ')
)


--Add computed columns to FT index
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[FT_Test] ADD ([TextData_FT1])
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[FT_Test] ADD ([TextData_FT2])


DELETE FROM dbo.FT_Test

INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '1  This is the chapter title' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '1.1  Section heading' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '1.1.1 paragraph 1 is very interesting' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '1.1.2 paragraph two is better' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '1.2 Another Section' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '1.2.1 Foobar qwerty loren ipsum' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '1.2.2 Foobar2 qwerty2 loren ipsum 12 items ' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '1.2.12 Foobar2 qwerty2 loren ipsum ' )
INSERT INTO dbo.FT_Test ( TextData )
VALUES  ( '2.2.17 sql server is great. ' )

--naive implementation
SELECT * FROM  ft_Test WHERE CONTAINS(TextData_ft1, '"1_1*"')
SELECT * FROM  ft_Test WHERE CONTAINS(TextData_ft1, '1*') 
SELECT * FROM  ft_Test WHERE CONTAINS(TextData_ft1, '2*') --
SELECT * FROM  ft_Test WHERE CONTAINS(TextData_ft1, '"1_1_2*"')
SELECT * FROM  ft_Test WHERE CONTAINS(TextData_ft1, '1_1_2*')

--only index the paragraph identifiers
SELECT * FROM  ft_Test WHERE CONTAINS(TextData_ft2, '"1_1*"')
SELECT * FROM  ft_Test WHERE CONTAINS(TextData_ft2, '1*') 
SELECT * FROM  ft_Test WHERE CONTAINS(TextData_ft2, '2*') --
SELECT * FROM  ft_Test WHERE CONTAINS(TextData_ft2, '"1_1_2*"')
SELECT * FROM  ft_Test WHERE CONTAINS(TextData_ft2, '1_1_2*')
```

Comment: thanks. but really seems to be a bit expensive. Is there really no way to let the fulltext engine know how to treat that dot differently?

Comment: Short of writing your own parser (which you don't want to do,  trust me), no.  This approach doesn't really add that much overhead, as the formula to replace the characters is only evaluated when the row is indexed, not when it's searched.  The parsers are part of the Windows searching functionality and work great for email messages, word documents, etc. For domain specific indexing, they have shortcomings.